# Can you change from `type` to `interface`?

Tags: typescript, typescript-types

I have types/interfaces that describe my API:

```
export type AddFileRequestApi = FormData

export interface AddMessageRequestApi {
  text: string;
  date: string;
}
```

Can I change `export type AddFileRequestApi = FormData` to use `interface`? E.g. something like this:

```
export interface AddFileRequestApi extends FormData
```

Comment: Yes, just add an empty body at the end (`{}`), since the body part of an interface isn't optional; [example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=55&pln=1&pc=53#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgQQBNCAxBAG2ACVgBHAV2AGcZ8wE5RUlCm4ToAWwAimGJjgBvAL5A) ([more here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#interfaces)). But why? And why have a type that's just an alias for `FormData`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Yes, just add an empty body at the end ({}), since the body part of an interface isn't optional; example (more here). But why? And why have a type that's just an alias for FormData?

T.J. Crowder from the comments on the question